# WCF - The maximum nametable character count quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data

Tags: c#, wcf, svcutil.exe, wcf-wshttpbinding

I'm having a WCF Service that uses wsHttpBinding. The server configuration is as follows :

```xml
<bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

At the client side I'm including the Service reference of the WCF-Service. It works great if I have limited functions say 90 Operation Contract in my IService but if add one more OperationContract than I'm unable to Update the Service reference nor i'm able to add that service reference. In [this](http://www.lazarciuc.ro/ioan/2009/05/28/wcf-contract-limits/) article it's mentioned that by changing those config files(i.e devenv.exe.config, WcfTestClient.exe.config and SvcUtil.exe.config) it will work but even including those bindings in those config files still that error pops up saying

There was an error downloading 'http://10.0.3.112/MyService/Service1.svc/mex'.
The request failed with HTTP status 400: Bad Request.
Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://10.0.3.112/MyService/Service1.svc/mex'.
There is an error in XML document (1, 89549).
The maximum nametable character count quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. The nametable is a data structure used to store strings encountered during XML processing - long XML documents with non-repeating element names, attribute names and attribute values may trigger this quota. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxNameTableCharCount property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 89549.
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Any idea how to solve this????

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

In the installation directory of your Visual Studio where devenv.exe is located (e.g. C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE) add this section to the devenv.exe.cofig

```
<system.serviceModel>
<client>
  <endpoint binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="largeServiceBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" name="http" />
</client>

<bindings>
  <customBinding>
    <!-- NOTE: The binding name must be the same as specified in the config file of the wcf service -->
    <binding name="largeServiceBinding" >
      <textMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </textMessageEncoding>

      <httpTransport transferMode="Buffered" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
    </binding>

  </customBinding>
</bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

in the app.config of your WCF-service add the same binding:

```
<bindings>
  <customBinding >
    <!-- NOTE: The binding name must be the same as specified in the devenv.exe.config file located ..\Common7\IDE folder of the VS installation directory -->
    <binding name="largeServiceBinding" >
      <textMessageEncoding>
        <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </textMessageEncoding>
      <httpTransport transferMode="Buffered" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
</bindings>
```

**Note that the name attribute of the binding tags from the two files must match** (e.g. largeServiceBinding)

Finally add the following mex endpoint into your service tag:

```
 <endpoint address="mex" binding="customBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" bindingName="testBinding" bindingConfiguration="largeServiceBinding" name="http"/>
```

this may look like this:

```
 <services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior"
    name="MyService.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="MyService.IMyService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="customBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" bindingName="testBinding" bindingConfiguration="largeServiceBinding" name="http"/>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8731/Design_Time_Addresses/MyService/MyService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply will try and let you know the result.

Comment: It worked Thanks. I had to change in the client the service endpoints settings after that it worked. Thanks!!!!

Comment: this also worked for me, but there was no need to add a new binding i just updated the `readerQuotas` with the above.

Answer (score 5):

I know it has been a while, but I got the same problem and found other (simpler) solution  [in codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/59150/ServiceModel-CommunicationException-maximum-nameta)

In the solution given there the values are set in the code rather than the .config file.

```
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 50000000;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 50000000;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 50000000;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 50000000;
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://server/EWS/Exchange.asmx"));
        ExchangeServicePortTypeClient ews = new ExchangeServicePortTypeClient(binding, endpoint);
```

However, I changed the values in the  relevant values in the .config file ( in both the `<binding>` and the `<readerQuotas>` sections) and solved the problem (rather than adding custom bindings):

```
                <binding name="ITransactionProcessor" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="50000000" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="50000000"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="50000000" maxArrayLength="50000000"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="50000000" />
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" 
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
```

I hope this will help somebody :)

Answer (score 1):

One thing to recognize is that the message refers to the svcutil reader quotas not the service ones! Svcutil has a limit on how much metadata it can read. This limit can be changed with a config file. The solution is to create a config file for svcutil and place it in the same folder as the tool. Next time you run svcutil, the config file values will be taken into account.

http://geekswithblogs.net/claraoscura/archive/2007/08/20/114806.aspx

Answer (score 1):

in your app.config or dll.config on the the client add:

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<netTcpBinding>
<binding name="myMex" maxReceivedMessageSize="1024000"> <!-- modify this to avoid stupid error -->
<readerQuotas maxNameTableCharCount="163840" /> <!-- DO NOT touch this one -->
<security mode="None" />
</binding>
</netTcpBinding>
</bindings>

...

<client>
<endpoint binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="myMex"
contract="IMetadataExchange" name="net.tcp" />

...

        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And there you go!
This is one of the really annoying things with WCF and as often google just yields you alot of bs. Wasted tons of time with this.